# ngIf consition with observables

Tags: angular

I've created two observables:

```
private sources$: Observable<Array<ISource>>;
private defaultSource$: Observable<ISource>;
```

I'm using `ngFor` in order to get all `ISource` and render them into a table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let source of sources$ | async; let index = index;">
...
```

For each source I'm creating several columns using `td` tag. In one of them:

```
<td>
    {{source.holdername}} <span class="tag tag-warning">DEFAULT</span>
</td>
```

I need that `span` tag is visible if the current `source` is the `defaultSource$`.

I'm guessing that I would need to use an `ngIf` but I'm not able to figure out how to build the expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to match `source` with any string which is coming from array on which you are iterating

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this :

```
<td>
    {{source.holdername}} <span class="tag tag-warning" *ngIf="source === (defaultSource$ | async)">DEFAULT</span>
</td>
```

Note that the value emitted by `defaultSource$` should be the same object reference as `source`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe defaultSource in OnInit method (with ngOnInit lifehook) and save source in variable if there is any new default source:

```
private currentDefaultSource: ISource;

public OnInit(): void {
    this.defaultSource$.subscribe(
        data => this.currentDefaultSource = data,
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Now, you have subscription and saved default source which be automatically updated. After that, you can use ngIf to do simple comparision.

```
<td>
    {{source.holdername}} <span *ngIf="source === currentDefaultSource" class="tag tag-warning">DEFAULT</span>
</td>
```

If you want, you can create function in your component and check it there. In HTML:

```
<td>
    {{source.holdername}} <span *ngIf="isDefaultSource(source)" class="tag tag-warning">DEFAULT</span>
</td>
```

And in your component:

```
isDefaultSource(source: ISource): boolean {
   return this.currentDefaultSource === source
}
```

Comment: `*ngIf="source === defaultSource"` you mean `*ngIf="source === currentDefaultSource"`, I guess.